# How to add new chrome user from extension? Is there any API available?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

chrome has a multiple user feature that allow user to maintain separate Google identities without logging out of the operating system, is there any API can be used from chrome extension to manager the multiple user account, for example, add/delete the user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API at the moment to manage profiles. You should feel free to file a feature request at http://new.crbug.com/, but as far as I know, nothing in that direction has been considered.